# CollapsingToolbarLayout not working properly

Tags: android, toolbar, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**Update:** this happens on Android 5.0 but it works just fine on 5.1. I filed this issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240) and it looks like it's gonna be included in the next release of the library

---

so I've been playing with the new [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and I've run into some issues. I think I've solved most of them, but I can't get this to work. Actually, not even the [provided example](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/) is working properly on my phone.

The problem is that when the toolbar is expanded, the icons are way too high. And when collapsed, they are simply gone. See screenshots.

I'm trying this on a Moto X running 5.0. I know this happens in more devices, but it actually works on some of them. Is this happening to you? Any known workaround?

[image: arrow and contextual menu are almost out of the screen]
[image: and they are gone here]

Comment: You might need to post some code for any help.

Comment: @Ranjith I left a link to the "official" repo (https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/) since that example is not working either

Comment: I tried that code from repo...That code worked perfectly for me....

Comment: @Ranjith yeah that's why I was asking. See screenshots to see what it does on my Moto X. And I know it's not working on a Nexus 7 either, but it seems to work on Nexus 5.

Comment: FYI, I just updated my Moto X to 5.1 and it's working fine now. So this is an issue with 5.0.

Comment: having this issue on a S6 with 5.02

Answer (score 4):

Fixed on

```
com.android.support:design:22.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this phenomenon will be in the android 5.0 and above

This is my way to solve：delete "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" in android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.

Like this ：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

Comment: removing fitsSystemWindows="true" gets the toolbar placement correct, but you lose being able to have your view extend into the statusbar.

Comment: i found now.I think this is a bug on android 5.0. I don not hava goog idea.sorry

Comment: I do not know if it is a bug on Android 5.0 or in this library, but it doesn't work on 5.0 and it does work on 5.1.

Comment: wasted 6 hours of my golden time on this shit, God bless you @M星空

Answer (score 1):

I fix it using set toolbar margin programmatically and set toolbar android:fitsSystemWindows="true".

On activity_detail.xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Related"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

on CheeseDetailActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String cheeseName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        int actionBarHeight = (int) (TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())
                - (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_padding_material))*2);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topMargin = - (actionBarHeight / 2);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(cheeseName);

    loadBackdrop();
}
```

Results:
http://s22.postimg.org/nnwi0mh41/initial.png
http://s22.postimg.org/8cmp00js1/collapsed.png

Answer (score 0):

That's a known bug in `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`.
It's already being fixed, it's marked as future release under google issues. So lets hope fix will be out soon.
Links with issues: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240
and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069

Comment: Yeah, actually it was me who filed that issue since I hadn't got any good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to collapsingToolBar layout : app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

it'll work

Answer (score -2):

remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: I'd recommend a bit of explanation rather than a  one line answer.